# mysql fetch array is not showing result

Tags: php, mysql

So I have been working on this code for a while. I believe I am really close. My `if` statement that is inside my `while` loop isn't showing any data in the area it's suppose to show. I know mysql is old and deprecated. I am going to change it once I figure this out.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventoryTable",$db);
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and sub = 'yes'",$db);
echo "<TABLE style=\"background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 10px solid A4A4A4;\">";
echo"<TR><TD>"."<B>Title</B>"."</td>";
echo"<TD>"."<B>Authors First Name</B>"."</td>";
echo"<TD>"."<B>Authors Last Name</B>"."</td>";
echo"<TD>"."<B>ISBN</B>"."</td>";
echo"<TD>"."<B>Publisher</B>"."</td>";
echo"<TD>"."<B>Course Number</B>"."</td>";
echo"<TD>"."<B>Source</B>"."</td></TR>";
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<TR><TD>".$myrow["title"]."</td>";
        echo "<TD>".$myrow["authorsFirst"]."</td>";
        echo"<TD>".$myrow["authorsLast"]."</td>";
        echo "<TD>".$myrow["ISBN"]."</td>";
        echo "<TD>".$myrow["publisher"]."</td>";
        echo "<TD>".$myrow["courseNum"]."</td>";
        while ($subResults = mysql_fetch_row($result2))
            {
                If($subResults == 'yes' )
            {
                echo "<td>".$myrow["source"]."</td>";
            } else {
                echo "<TD>"."Please subscribe to View"."</td>";
        }
                echo "</TABLE>";
        }
    }
?>
```

This is the part of my code that isn't showing any results. 
while

```
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<TR><TD>".$myrow["title"]."</td>";
        echo "<TD>".$myrow["authorsFirst"]."</td>";
        echo"<TD>".$myrow["authorsLast"]."</td>";
        echo "<TD>".$myrow["ISBN"]."</td>";
        echo "<TD>".$myrow["publisher"]."</td>";
        echo "<TD>".$myrow["courseNum"]."</td>";
        while ($subResults = mysql_fetch_row($result2))
            {
                If($subResults == 'yes' )
            {
                echo "<td>".$myrow["source"]."</td>";
            } else {
                echo "<TD>"."Please subscribe to View"."</td>";
        }
                echo "</TABLE>";
        }
    }
```

I want my session user to be able to see the source from my inventory table if they have a yes in the sub field. If they do not have a yes in the sub field, they will see `please subscribe to view`. Am i doing the `mysql_fetch` incorrectly or is there a problem because I have 2 while loops going on at once.

Comment: Apart from the =/== issue – $username likely contains a string value, yes? But what you are comparing it to is an array.

Comment: And of course your inner while loops only once, on the first iteration of the outer while loop. After that, `mysql_fetch_array($result2)` will continue to return false, so the loop body isn’t executed any more. You’ll need to use `mysql_data_seek` to reset the record pointer for that result set, if you want to loop over it again.

Comment: And the MySQL extension has been deprecated for long time now already, and has been completely removed in PHP 7. You should be using MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: @CBroe - the OP knows that and posted this"... I know mysql is old and deprecated. I am going to change it once I figure this out. ..." indicating that will be fixed in due course

Comment: $username is from the session. `mysql_data_seek` requires 2 parameters. What should I use as an offset if I am searching the table?

Answer (score 1):

you need to have "==" to compare two values, otherwise you assign the second value to the first variable:

```
...If($username == $subResults)...
```

or to use a strict comparison of type and content, use "==="

```
If($username === $subResults)
```

also I am thinking the code should be

```
...If($subResults ==="yes"){echo"....///desired content";}else{echo"...//alternate content";}...
```

and you are missing the echo statement and closing `</td>` in the code

```
   "<td>".$myrow["source"];
```

should be

```
echo"<td>".$myrow["source"]."</td>";
```

in fact - aren't you missing the closing td's in all of the cells?

Comment: Nothing shows under `code`"<td>".$myrow["source"];`code` still. The row is just blank but every other row loads data from my inventory table correctly.

Comment: answer amended - look at the last half :)

Comment: I am getting an error now. The error says syntax error, unexpected '"<TD>"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'  on line 42. Line 42 is  `code`<TD>".$myrow["authorsFirst"]."</td>"`code`

Comment: that would proabably be becuase the preceding TD isn't being closed - you need to go through and close all TD's that have been opened  as well as the TR. also - i just noticed that your border styling is wrong too - you need a "#" before the border color declaration ... "#A4A4A4"...

Comment: I am no longer getting an error. "Please subscribe to View" is showing up 7 times though. I thought it was showing up 7 times because there may have been 7 users in my users table. There's 10 so it can't be that.

Comment: probably there are 7 table cells in your row - perhaps its best if you trashed the entire code as it is an rewrote it carefully, making sure that you have all code structure correct

Comment: I edited my old post with my new code. Can I have multiple `code`mysql_query`code` in one <?php ?> area?

Comment: yup - also look at the rest of your code for errors - eg: <TD><B>Source</B></TR>"; should be <TD><B>Source</B></TD></TR>"; ... and I would suggest losing the capitalisation on these elements. best we don't keep commenting on this though- SO has a policy of restricting comments and reducing chat on posts - good luck with your code